# Adding code markup for questions/answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Does anyone know how to add code markup for questions & answers in this forum?

In Stack Overflow, one can do something like this:

<!-- language: c# -->

```
var some = "code in here";
```

and it will do some syntax highlighting (for example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14905000/866454))

On this website however we don't seem to have syntax highlight options. Anyone has a clue if this can be added?

Comment: I was missing it too

Comment: What programming languages are used together with Tridion?

Comment: Mostly c# & Java, sometimes XSLT, and - like with any Web-oriented system - Javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per this Meta Stack Overflow question and its first answer: [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) it sounds like two things have to happen:

1. We need one of the SE Community Managers to turn on automatic syntax highlighting for the site
2. As we add tags such as c#, javascript, xml etc. which should have language specific highlighting, we need a diamond level moderator to set the syntax hightlighting format for the specific tag.

Given this I am going to flag this post as needing moderator attention

Answer (score 6):

This is enabled now. Since questions are often asked and answered without a language tag attached to them, I've enabled the default highlighting (using automatic language detection) on all posts - the special `<!-- language:...` comments can be used to override this where necessary (this is primarily useful for languages that aren't auto-detected, and to turn off highlighting altogether).

Because languages are often mixed (XML+C#, etc), **moderators should not override this auto-detection for specific tags unless absolutely necessary** (Visual Basic derivatives might be one case where overriding the default *is* desirable, since they're not auto-detected).

Comment: Thanks for turning this on for us @Shog9